Animating GIFs as previews in File Manager "LF" or "ranger"
The desired behavior: When I'm using a file manager "LF" I would like to have animated GIFs as previews when I am over an image/gif mime-type file.
What I actually had on mind was to convert videos to 3-4 second GIFs and then use those GIFs as an animated preview of the first 3-4 seconds of that video.
I was using ffmpeg to convert a video to 4 second GIF:
ffmpeg -t 4 -ss 0 -i file_name.mp4 -vf "fps=15,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos" -c:v gif output.gif
But that is beside the point.
My only concern, right now, is: Is it even possible to do that in any file manager?
I was using "ranger" and now I'm using "LF".
I've found a program called "chafa" which is indeed able to animate GIFs inside a terminal emulator.
However if I try to tweak "lfrc" such that the preview shows GIFs, I'm unable to do that. I've managed to animate it "within the terminal" while the "LF" is running, but not as a preview. It stops showing files and shows the image and then when I quit, it again displays files within the "LF".
Example usage:
$chafa --view-size 50x70 --animate true filename.gif
I've configured "LF" in its configuration file, "lfrc", to run a preview_gif.sh script.
#!/bin/sh
chafa --size=75x85 --colors=256 --animate true "$f"

And I've mapped it like this:
map - 
map - $~/.config/lf/preview_gif.sh

Preview of a GIF in "LF" looks like this:

However, when I press "-", it starts animating but not as a preview:

In the Documentation of LF it says that you can preview images using chafa, by having a terminal with sixel support.
The only terminal that supports sixel and that "wanted" to display images on the terminal using img2sixel  was "wezterm".
Wezterm did show image previews using chafa(GIFs were previewed as a static image), however when I tried to change "--animate false" to "--animate true", it "breaks". It starts displaying weird characters instead of animating the GIF.
Here are two pictures that show what is it that I've tried with wezterm:


Then I tried to just display two images one-by-one in the preview pane. I hard-coded which two pictures should be displayed and in which order.
This is what my previewer.sh script looked like:
#!/bin/sh
case "$(file -Lb --mime-type -- "$1")" in
    image/*)
        chafa -f sixel -s "$2x$3" --animate off --polite on "/home/vuk/Pictures/ascii_table.png"
        sleep 2
        printf "\033[3;61H"
        chafa -f sixel -s "$2x$3" --animate off --polite on "/home/vuk/Pictures/Ron_0.png"

        exit 1
        ;;
    *)
        cat "$1"
        ;;
esac

And while that did put both pictures in the "preview" pane, it displayed them at the same time, even though I wrote to display one and then wait 2 seconds and then display the other.

Then, I was curios if it was even possible to display two things one-by-one, with a delay between.
That's when I wrote this:
#!/bin/sh
case "$(file -Lb --mime-type -- "$1")" in
image/*)
~/.scripts/try_this.sh
exit 1
;;
*)
cat "$1"
;;
esac
try_this.sh:
#!/bin/bash
echo "one"
sleep 2
echo "two"

You may wonder why I wrote it by calling an external script. I did that because many things didn't work when I directly wrote them under image/*) option so I wanted to try another way.
I even tried doing an empty looping as a form of delay, but that didn't change anything either.
This is what it looks like when I'm calling this "try_this.sh" script as a form of a preview:
(Again, it waits and then displays both at the same time. It doesn't display "one" and the waits 2 seconds and then displays "two". It first waits 2 seconds and then displays both)


Since I didn't succeed, I've tried to go with "ranger".
Here "something" is happening, but it still doesn't work.
Here is my ranger "rifle.conf" and the preview that is generated by it(respectively)


I'm basically out of options. Any hints, suggestions, advices would be greatly appreciated. Is it even possible to display one-by-one in the preview pane?
It seems so obviously possible, for some reason, but I can't make it work. Maybe I'm mistaken.
Thanks for reading.
